property getter does not reflect value of closure variable
I am confused by the way property getters interact with constructor closure.
Below is a minimal example:


function Ctor() {
  let closureX = 0
  
  Object.assign(this, {
    get publicX() { return closureX }
  })
  
  closureX++
  console.log(closureX)
}

let o = new Ctor()
console.log(o.publicX)



Why is o.publicX not changing when closureX does ?

Because Object.assign just assigns the values to the keys, so the getter is imemdiately invoked, returns 0 and then assigns it to the object. This is not true if you use defineProperty. For example, you are still allowed to set publicX as its just a value assigned to a key on the object, it has a getter and a setter, your defined getter is not "assigned", it is read and then assigned.

It is simply because that's what Object.assign does - it does not assign getters or setters, it assigns the values associated with the keys to the other object. MDN Docs already clarifies that getters will be invoked on the source and setters will be invoked on the target:

The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object. It uses [[Get]] on the source and [[Set]] on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters. Therefore it assigns properties, versus copying or defining new properties. This may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters.

That last sentence is exactly what you are trying to do and it will not work.
You can verify this be checking its property descriptor and seeing that the new object did not inherit the getter from the source object, only the value that getter returns:


const object = Object.assign({}, {
    get publicX(){ return 3; }
});

console.log( object );

const definition = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( object, 'publicX' )

console.log( definition ); // No getter defined, just a value



If you do want to accomplish this, the solution would probably be the old-fashioned Object.defineProperty to assign the getter:


function Ctor(){
  
  let closureX = 0;
  
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'publicX', {
      get(){ return closureX; }
  });
  
  closureX++;

}

const ctor = new Ctor();

console.log( ctor.publicX ); // It now returns the internal variable!




thanks, is there a way to get what I want here - a property that return the closure variable (without going through self) ?

Object.defineProperty( this, 'publicX', { get(){ return closureX; } }) should do the trick! If you then use the getOwnPropertyDescriptor you will see that it no longer holds a value but only a getter. There is also defineProperties if you want to do this for multiple keys at once, but you will have to write them like definition objects and not just 'get/set' I guess.

I amended my answer with an example of how this actually should work...

Note that you might want to pass enumerable: true as part of the Object.defineProperty() options. This makes the property enumerable, meaning that it shows up when using for (const key in ctor), Object.keys(ctor), etc.

You already learnt the why. Now, a way to 'solve' this is to create a factory function. Additional advantage may be that with a factory you don't need the new keyword anymore. For example:


function XFactory(closureX = 0) {
  return Object.freeze({
    get X() { return closureX; },
    set X(value) { closureX = value; },
    get incrementX() { closureX += 1; return closureX; },
    get decrementX() { closureX -= 1; return closureX; },
  });
}

const o = XFactory();

console.log(`o.X => ${o.X}`);
o.X = 15;
console.log(`o.X = 15; o.X => ${o.X}`);
console.log(`o.incrementX => ${o.incrementX}`);
console.log(`o.decrementX => ${o.decrementX}`);

const x = XFactory(41);
console.log(`The meaning of life is ${x.incrementX} (x.incrementX)`);



I actually stopped using constructors a couple of years ago and use factories for all kinds of code in a class free object oriented fashion. For example in this flagged enum factory.

You seem very opinionated about that )defo reading your profile :) ), but is there nothing inside you that thinks "waw that looks so incredibly dense"? I think being hardline one way or the other ain't the solution anyway, but that's neither here nor there.

I am opiniated for sure, but wouldn't call myself a hardliner. What do you mean with 'that' in what you think I should think about ("waw that looks ... etc")?

I mean your code and the factory system here, but don't take it offensively. Just find it interesting. Your profile came across as a "this way or the highway" but that could be my misreading :) Also, factories aren't exclusive to functional programming, you could just call new Something() and return that. Either way, the only reason I kinda wanted to comment is that it feels like it's not really "solving" the problem, just trying to seel a different way of doing it as preferred?

That's why in my answer solve was between quotes ;P

Anyway, modified my profile somewhat. In the end, who wants to be seen as a hardliner? There are enough of those walking the earth already :D

Oh man sorry I gave you that impression :D Might have been to hard an fast with my conclusion there! Anyways, good interaction :)

I tend to avoid using Constructors these days, and keep most things closure based.  But one area were the prototype is still useful is when generating thousands of instances, as one disadvantage of the factory pattern is memory usage, as each instance has duplicated methods, although some of this can be mitigated of course using bind.

@Keith my understanding is that modern js engines heavily optimise duplicate methods so it's a non issue.. didn't test myself

@Keith: I have a StringBuilder module programmed in a class free object oriented way. The demo contains a performance test for it. Using SHIFT+ESC in Chrome you can check its memory footprint. It doesn't look like an issue.

@KooiInc  Yeah, optimizations in JS are pretty good these days, but it wasn't performance I was referring too, it was memory usage.  A quick test here doing a simple Point class with 1 single method, the memory usage for a class was 3 times smaller, and of course the more methods you add the bigger the difference.  To be fair it's unlikely it would be an issue for most use cases, but if you wanted to create millions of instances a class might still be a good candidate, especially for low memory devices.

let me break the constructor defination function for you.
  Object.assign(this, {
        get publicX() { return closureX }
      })

The Object.assign() is a  static method that copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.
and get syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.
this is whole brief in short.
so when you copied the variable , its a deep copy means changes which are implemented further is not higlighted in the copied one.
i hope this will help.

What? "its a deep copy means changes which are implemented further is not higlighted in the copied one." - I am so very confused by the wording here.

so think of it like that A getter method publicX is defined using Object.assign. When publicX is accessed, the current value of closureX is returned. This getter provides read-only access to closureX but does not bind to the variable itself—rather, it retrieves its current value whenever called.

Stop explaining it on the fly and think about how to interpret what you are saying, because although this makes sense in your head, it's not coming across. The point is that the getter does not get assigned, it gets executed and the value from that gets assigned. I'm just trying to push you towards writing a better answer.

I understand there was a bit of confusion about the getter function. Let me explain it more clearly.
In the post, it is mentioned that the "get" syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up. This means that whenever we try to access this property, the getter function is called to return its value.

In my comment, when I referred to the getter, I was specifically talking about the publicx function. The key point of our discussion is that whenever this function returns closurex, it is returning the current value at that moment in time. It does not return the variable itself.
Therefore, if you change the value after it has been returned through the getter function, it won't affect the previously returned value. The returned value is a snapshot of the value at the time the getter function was called.

This was my first post, and I was just trying to solve the issue. Thank you for pushing me. I hope I will be able to explain more clearly in the future.

Well don't give up and keep trying, though I feel instead of clarifying it in the comments to me, you're better off trying to rewrite your post to be more clear altogether! (Note: dont be discouraged - personally I dont downvote any posts from newcomers so they dont immediately get scared away). Anyways, welcome to SO!
